# Working with Youtube Google API & jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, youtube-api

I'm iterating through each li that is generated by the db which produces a youtube link to the video I want to link to So essentially I have this:

```
<ul id="mediaList">
    <li>
        <p>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOm-myVLmKU</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odNde8wQ5uA</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to iterate through each li item, grab the youtube link, grab the video id and then retrieve the JSON data and what the ultimate goal is, is to add an image tag of the thumbnail for that video into the list item for media list

To accomplish this I have this jquery code(Please note using no conflict so $ becomes $j):

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

$j("#mediaList li").each(function (){

    var u = $j(this).find("p").text();
    var reqStart = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
    var reqSettings = "?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?";
    var vid = grabytvid(u);

    var request = reqStart + vid + reqSettings;

    $j.getJSON(request, function(data) {
        var y = (data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].url);

    });

    $j(this).append('<img src="' + y + '" alt="" />');

    });
});
```

Where I'm making use of the Youtube API Feed call:

[http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[Video_ID_Here]?v=2](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%5bVideo_ID_Here%5d?v=2)

For your reference grabytvid is a function that just splits and grabs the video id:

```
function grabytvid(ystring)
{
    var v = ystring.split("=").pop();
    return v;
}
```

Are there any ideas where I'm going wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You `y` isn't defined in `$j(this).append('<img src="' + y + '" alt="" />');` as you set `y` only inside the `getJSON` function

I would do it this way

```
$("#mediaList li").each(function() {

    var self = this, u = $(this).find("p").text();
    var reqStart = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
    var reqSettings = "?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?";
    var vid = grabytvid(u);

    var request = reqStart + vid + reqSettings;

    $.getJSON(request, function(data) {
        var y = (data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].url);
        $(self).append('<img src="' + y + '" alt="" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Went with this technique, it ultimately ended up being a connection issue to googles api(never had a successful json request) but this certainly solved the scope error and grabbing a local self variable referencing this helped me more in the longrun

Answer (score 1):

Please note that y is not in-scope when you call it:

`$j(this).append('<img src="' + y + '" alt="" />');`

I recommend performing the following change:

```
var y;

$.getJSON(request, function(data) {
   y = (data.entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"][0].url);

});
```

Hope this helps, Enjoy life.

Comment: This also worked and fixed the scope error, but the local variable for this was what had me go with the above answer.